# Remove Chatter not enabled from Community Template

Tags: customer-community, community-builder

I am hoping to use a Community template, however I am not quite sure if I'm able to turn this off:

[image]

I would really like to hide this message as I don't want the Community Users to see this when they look at the record.  The only thing I can think of is to add Chatter to the Object and remove the Quick Actions from the page of the Community Users... however, they'd still see a "nothing is here" if no posts occur.

All of my finding has to deal with turning chatter on or off... can't find anything about this particular message :/

Answer (score 4):

You can remove that by following these steps:

1. Select "Record Detail page" within Page selection list (within Lightning Community Builder)
2. Select Tabs component
3. Set Tab 3 to "None" (refer screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

find the Class Id of the text tag and put in your CSS for site to hide it something like

```css
.cuf-chatterNotEnabledText.cuf-center.uiOutputText
{
    
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your in community - Go to community builder -> Theme layout -> edit Css ->add this css

```
.forceCommunityRecordHomeTabs .recordHomeSecondaryContent {
    display: none;
}
```